# Time factor in Client server program to measure upload and download time of video file

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have completed client server program to download and upload a video(media) file, but I am unable to figure out how to calculate the upload, download time separately and make it run repeatedly to measure improvement in time? I will be running client at one IP and server at different IP.

Source code of the client;

```
package wdc;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
        int bytesRead;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3248);
            is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (is != null) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\file1.avi");
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
                do {
                    baos.write(aByte);
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
                } while (bytesRead != -1);
                bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the source code of the server side;

```
package wds;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
            Socket connectionSocket = null;
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;
            try {
                welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
                connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }
            if (outToClient != null) {
                File myFile = new File("C:\\file2.avi");
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                try {
                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.flush();
                    outToClient.close();
                    connectionSocket.close();
                    // File sent, exit the main method
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow it's not necessary to put whole code try to put code which is related to your problem so that it can help us to find appropriate solution.

Comment: okay. i actually wanted to add time factor to measure upload and download time